# It is possible hide 'New Event' button in lightning Community?

Tags: lightning-community, event, partner-communities

[image: Im using standard calendar in lightning community and already remove the Edit Event permission from the logged user]

It is possible to remove the new event button? (Im using standard calendar in lightning community and already remove the Edit Event permission from the logged user)

I want this because New event action CANNOT be override IN COMMUNITIES by a lightning component.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are in the community, yes you can do this by adding a CSS override.

You can edit the community CSS overrides here:
[image]

You will then need to examine the html of the edit button, but it's going to be very similar to this:

```
<ul class="branding-actions slds-button-group oneActionsRibbon forceActionsContainer" >
  <li class="slds-button slds-button--neutral slds-truncate" >
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" title="New Event" 
      class="forceActionLink" role="button">
      <div class="slds-truncate" title="New Event" >New Event</div>
    </a></li>
</ul>
```

(Right click on the button and choose 'inspect' to see the html and css structure)

In the `Edit CSS` area you will need to target the css + html structure of the button.

Something like this:

```
.branding-actions.slds-button-group.oneActionsRibbon.forceActionsContainer .forceActionLink[title="New Event"]{
  display:none;
}
```

Hit save, publish the community and it should work.

Comment: Great explanation, thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

In the year since this answer was written, Salesforce has changed the HTML.

So, the CSS I came up with that solves this requirement today is:

```
.slds-button.slds-button_neutral.new-event-button {display:none}
```