# Hide filter option on report side in experience cloud

Tags: css, experience-cloud

we are setting up the experience cloud and want to give some reports to our external users. However what we would like to avoid is them playing around with filters. Is it possible to use CSS to hide the filter icon?[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: related: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/296984/it-is-possible-hide-new-event-button-in-lightning-community (answer is YES BTW)

Comment: Thanks for reaching out @cropredy . I came across this entry before but unfortunetaly I have little to no CSS Skills which makes it impossible for me to translate the syntax to my case :/

Comment: OK, to help, I'm going to need to see the entire HTML for the page that displays the Report in your Community. There's no parent CSS selector so we need to find an unambiguous selector up higher on the page to help set the lower selector to `display:none`. Also, with the full HTML, you can also get help on the stackoverflow site

Comment: Hi 
did u managed to archive this? 
Im having the same issue

Comment: Hey @IdanTouito we were not able to hide the filter icon. What we did is "lock" the filters inside the reports so that they cannot be changed by the community user